# Using $lookup aggregation for only count purpose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to use $lookup aggregation in order to know how many documents in the other collection, so no need to to grab the whole documents, which's, in this case, will give me an exception because the size of the total document exceeded the 16MB limit. 
the exception I got

```
MongoError: Total size of documents in visits matching pipeline's $lookup stage exceeds 104857600 bytes
```

the query

```
Link.aggregate(
            [
                {$match: {...query}},
                { 
                    $lookup: {
                    from:"visits",
                    localField: "_id",
                    foreignField: "linkId",
                    as: "visits"
                    }
                },
                { 
                    $addFields: { totalVisits: { $size: "$visits" } },
                },
                {
                    $sort: {totalVisits: -1}
                }
            ]
        )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can return [$count](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/count/) from [custom $lookup pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#join-conditions-and-uncorrelated-sub-queries):

```
{
    $lookup: {
        from: "visits"
        let: { id: "$_id" },
        pipeline: [
            { $match: { $expr: { $eq: [ "$$id", "$linkId" ] } } },
            { $count: "total" }
        ],
        as: "totalVisits"
    }
}
```